# Accessing bytes in an FBO

Tags: opengl, texture2d, fbo

I have rendered a texture to an FBO in the hope that I can now apply effects to that texture before displaying it. I cant work out how to access the FBO array to change it. Any idea? Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you elaborate it? Shaders aren't enough for you?

Comment: An FBO is not an array. It is just a state container for various render targets, and the render targets in itself aren't arrays either, the data layout is much more complicated (and especially optimized) than just a 2D array.

Comment: @derhass You mean the final image that gets sent to the display device (monitor) isn't just a 2D array? What does it look like then?

Comment: @Zebrafish: the internal layout for renderbuffers and textures is completely vendor-specific. Vendors typically implement framebuffer compresssion to reduce memory bandwidth usage. Texture layout is typically tiled and makes use of space fitting curves ([see ryg's blog article here](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/texture-tiling-and-swizzling/)) to improve cache locality.

Answer (score 1):

Could you specify what you mean by adding effects?  The basic idea of a fbo is to render everything to that fbo and then apply that fbo to a texture.  If you wish to know how to bind that framebuffer to a texture, simple create and setup a texture with an empty data set for `glTexImage2D`.  Then, call `glFramebufferTexture2D` with your framebuffer object bound and pass in your texture as one of the arguments.  To render to your framebuffer, call `glBindFramebuffer`.  To bind your framebuffer texture, simply call `glBindTexture`, like any other texture.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough. I am rendering a scene which includes water and reflections of trees / plants etc. Some of the plants are very low detail (low poly). I want to apply a rippling effect to the reflections but because of the low vertex count the effect looks ugly. I was hoping that by rendering first to an fbo I would have access to individual pixels and that would allow me to apply much nicer rippling effects (by manipulating the final rendered texture rather than the vertexes).